# Invalid content was found starting with element 'employee'. One of '{contractemployee}' is expected

Tags: xml, xsd

I have to generate XML and XSD from an entity relationship diagram. My XML is correct but I am not able to validate the XSD i generated with this XML document as it throws up an *error: Invalid content was found starting with element 'employee'. One of '{contractemployee}' is expected.*

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<company>
<companyname>capgemini</companyname>
<address>mumbai</address>
    <department>
        <dname>software</dname>
        <deptphoneno>9876543210</deptphoneno>
        <deptfaxno>0447654321</deptfaxno>
        <deptemail>soft@capgemini.com</deptemail>
            <employee>
                <empid>101</empid>
                <ename>rajat</ename>
                <emailid>rajat@capgemini.com</emailid>
                <phoneno>9876543211</phoneno>
            </employee>
            <contractemployee>
                <name>jade</name>
                <phoneno>9882507167</phoneno>
            </contractemployee>
    </department>
</company>
```

**XSD:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:element name="company">
        <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="companyname" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="address" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="department">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="dname" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="deptphoneno" type="xsd:long"/>
                        <xsd:element name="deptfaxno" type="xsd:int"/>
                        <xsd:element name="deptemail" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="employee">
                            <xsd:complexType>
                                <xsd:sequence>
                                    <xsd:element name="empid" type="xsd:int"/>
                                    <xsd:element name="ename" type="xsd:string"/>
                                    <xsd:element name="emailid" type="xsd:string"/>
                                    <xsd:element name="phoneno" type="xsd:long"/>
                                </xsd:sequence>
                            </xsd:complexType>
                        </xsd:element>
                        <xsd:element name="contractemployee">
                            <xsd:complexType>
                                <xsd:sequence>
                                    <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                                    <xsd:element name="phoneno" type="xsd:long"/>
                                </xsd:sequence>
                            </xsd:complexType>
                        </xsd:element>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close to the answer. According to the E-R diagram, there is 1- many mandatory relationship between department and employee while 1-many optional relationship between department and contract employee. Whenever there is optional relationship, we use minOccurs="0".

I'm posting both the XML & XSD so you can understand it better.
**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<company
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='companyxsd.xsd'>
    <companyname>Capgemini</companyname>
    <address>Mumbai</address>
    <department>
        <dname>Operations</dname>
        <deptphoneno>987610</deptphoneno>
        <deptfaxno>223654</deptfaxno>
        <deptemail>op@gmail.com</deptemail>
        <employee>
            <empid>20</empid>
            <ename>Mukesh</ename>
            <emailid>mukesh@gmail.com</emailid>
            <phoneno>967642</phoneno>
        </employee>
        <contractemployee>
            <name>Ramesh</name>
            <phoneno>25643</phoneno>
        </contractemployee>
    </department>
</company>
```

The XSD for this XML:
**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="company">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="companyname" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
<xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
<xs:element name="department" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="dname" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
<xs:element name="deptphoneno" type="xs:long"></xs:element>
<xs:element name="deptfaxno" type="xs:long"></xs:element>
<xs:element name="deptemail" type="xs:string"></xs:element>


<xs:element name="employee" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="empid" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
<xs:element name="ename" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
<xs:element name="emailid" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
<xs:element name="phoneno" type="xs:long"></xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="contractemployee" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
<xs:element name="phoneno" type="xs:long"></xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: 1-many optional the only part where i didn't pay much attention :P
thanks for the help :)